# How to create SWIG typemap for function that takes and returns 2 tables

Tags: lua, swig, typemaps

This is my SWIG typemap:

```
%apply (float *INOUT, int) {(float *io1, int n1)};
%apply (float *INOUT, int) {(float *io2, int n2)};
```

And This is my function:

```
 void process(float *io1, int n1, float *io2, int n2)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n1; ++i)
        {
            io1[i] = io1[i] * 0.1;
            io2[i] = io2[i] * 0.1;
        }
    }
```

I expect the `process` function to take 2 tables and return 2 tables.

In Lua, the `process` function seems to return 2 tables but it only returns the same 2 tables which is passed from the first argument.

For example In Lua, when I run the following:

```
local a, b = {3}, {4}
local c, d = process(a, b)
print(c[1], d[1])
```

The result I get:

```
0.3 0.3
```

But I expect:

```
0.3 0.4
```

How should I change the SWIG typemap to make it work as expected?

Comment: Cannot reproduce.  This example outputs `0.30000001192093 0.40000000596046` as expected: http://dpaste.com/3YW77DN

Comment: @HenriMenke It's good to see you Henri. I will check again. Thank you. :)

Comment: @HenriMenke I'm sorry it was my mistake. It works as expected. I will be more careful next time. Can I give you the bounty anyway? (how?)

Comment: I think the only way to give him the bounty is that he answer the question and you accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your problem with the following minimal example.

**`test.i`**

```c
%module example
%{
#include "test.h"
%}

%include <typemaps.i>

%apply (float *INOUT, int) {(float *io1, int n1)};
%apply (float *INOUT, int) {(float *io2, int n2)};

%include "test.h"
```

**`test.h`**

```c
#pragma once

void process(float *io1, int n1, float *io2, int n2);
```

**`test.c`**

```c
#include "test.h"

void process(float *io1, int n1, float *io2, int n2) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n1; ++i) {
        io1[i] = io1[i] * 0.1;
        io2[i] = io2[i] * 0.1;
    }
}
```

**`test.lua`**

```lua
local example = require("example")
local a, b = {3}, {4}
local c, d = example.process(a, b)
print(c[1], d[1])
```

Then I compile and run using

```
$ swig -lua test.i
$ cc -fPIC -shared -I /usr/include/lua5.3/ test_wrap.c test.c -o example.so                                             
$ lua5.3 test.lua
0.30000001192093    0.40000000596046
```

The garbage values after the 7th decimal digit stem from the promotion of `float` to `lua_Number` which is `double` by default.

Disregarding this, I see the expected `0.3 0.4`.  That means the error must be in some code that you have not shown.  Make sure to `%apply` the typemaps *before* parsing the prototype of `process`, i.e. in the example above note how `%apply` comes before `%include "test.h"`.